# Sorting list by comparing datetimes

Tags: python, list, sorting, datetime

there is a list consist of time and query, such as:

```
data = [['bbb', '2017-10-24 07:23:02'], 
        ['ccc', '2017-10-24 11:01:00'], 
        ['aaa', '2017-10-24 16:13:32']]
```

I want to sort it by time. Both the query and time are string type. How can I realize it?

Well I convert it to

```
[['aaa', 16,13,32],
 ['bbb', 7,23,2],
['ccc', 11,1,0],...]
```

regardless of the day since all the days are the same.

Comment: As always, convert first.

Comment: For this particular time format, a lexical sort (sort by string) will actually do just fine…

Comment: As @deceze stated, lexicographical sorting works for datetimes in ISO format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, sorting works on the string counterparts too. However, I'd like to provide a more canonical version for anybody interested.

[`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) from the `pandas` module is my goto method for most `datetime` related operations because of how good it is at guessing date formats.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [['bbb', '2017-10-24 07:23:02'], 
            ['ccc', '2017-10-24 11:01:00'], 
            ['aaa', '2017-10-24 16:13:32']]  
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x[1]))
```

Which gives:

```
[['bbb', '2017-10-24 07:23:02'], 
 ['ccc', '2017-10-24 11:01:00'], 
 ['aaa', '2017-10-24 16:13:32']]
```

---

You can also use the inbuilt [`dateutil.parser`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#module-dateutil.parser) to infer datetime formats:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x[1]))
```

Which gives the same result.

---

If you're stuck in a position where you cannot convert without passing a format, use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and explicitly pass a format string.

Answer (score 0):

logical operatos like *<*, >=, and etc are implemented for `datetime` objects.
So I suggest to convert strings to datetime objects in order to sort them:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = [
        ['aaa', '2017-10-24 16:13:32'],
        ['bbb', '2017-10-24 07:23:02'],
        ['ccc', '2017-10-24 11:01:00']
]


sorted_dates = sorted(data, key= lambda x: datetime.strptime(
                                            x[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
)

print(sorted_dates)
```